# Run Javascript function in background of NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have written a function that periodically checks the battery statuses of connected android devices and returns an array. How can I run this function on server startup and have it continuously running while providing its information to other pages?

```
var minutes = 1, the_interval = minutes * 60 * 500;
setInterval(function() {
adb.devices().then(function(devices) {

    var promises = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++){
        promises.push(adb.checkBattery(devices[i]));
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then(function(availableDevices) {
        console.log('Updated:');
        console.log(availableDevices);
        return availableDevices;
    });
});
}, the_interval);
```

This is my app.js file which was automatically created when I opened a new project. I added app.use for the various routes I have created.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var adb     = require('./adb.js');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var devices = require('./routes/devices');
var openBrowser = require('./routes/openBrowser');
var closeBrowser = require('./routes/closeBrowser');
var openApp = require('./routes/openApp');
var closeApp = require('./routes/closeApp');
var install = require('./routes/install');
var uninstall = require('./routes/uninstall');
var pull = require('./routes/pull');
var push = require('./routes/push');
var battery = require('./routes/battery');


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/devices', devices);
app.use('/openBrowser', openBrowser);
app.use('/openApp', openApp);
app.use('/closeApp', closeApp);
app.use('/install', install);
app.use('/closeBrowser', closeBrowser);
app.use('/uninstall', uninstall);
app.use('/pull', pull);
app.use('/push', push);
app.use('/battery', battery);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

using express, if i understand correctly, you should run it in some interval :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.listen(3000, function () {
    yourFunction();
    setInterval(yourFunction, << period in ms >>);
});

function yourFunction()
{
    << your code >>
}
```

if u want to use your function reacting on some request to your web server, you better to use middleware :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(function(req,res) {
    if(condition)
        yourFunction();
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
});

function yourFunction()
{
    << your code >>
}
```

Comment: Which file would this be placed in? app.js?

Comment: or index.js, any name you want)

Comment: if u already have an app been make, you better to show it's code as well.

Comment: I placed it inside app.js which is inside my views folder. When I start the server it says that Port 3000 is already in use. Note: I have already created other pages/routes which can be accessed upon starting the server and going to the specific URL. Could there be a conflict between these .js files inside routes and the newly created function in app.js?

Comment: looks like you have you root js file somewhere, which is running web server before your new app.js, that's why 3000 port is in use.

Comment: I uploaded my app.js code. I placed the function within this one.

Comment: maybe you have two app.listen() functions is app.js, check it

Comment: I have a server.listen(port) line inside my www.js file.

Comment: if u use this code as interval you should use it in your www.js

Answer (score 0):

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrJK1.png) According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#why-use-process-nexttick) you can use

```
server = app.listen(3000, function () {
});

server.on('listening', () => {
   your function()
})
```

Comment: Can you add link to the documentation (to this information, not to main documentation page)?